# ios how is permission/Authorization working?

Tags: ios, permissions, authorization, ios-permissions

I'am trying to find how the iOS permissions and authorizations works, but I can't find anything.

What I want to know is, if in my app version 1.1. I ask user for location's permission and when I update my app to 1.2, I now ask for location and camera. Is the app going to ask again for location permission will it just ask for the camera's permission ?

Comment: The app just asks once for each permission, if the user gave or denied access. But you can check if permission was given and if there is no permission you can send the user to the settings app to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes. The app will ask for the location and camera both permissions in your new app.

Also, this is more complicated when it comes to location access. There are 2 cases:

1) Foreground Permission: Your app asks for permission to use the location when you app is in foreground. In this case, when your app is in foreground only then it can access location. And it will ask for permission everytime it comes to foreground and tries to use location.

2) Background Permission: In case your app wants to use location even when it is in background, then it will ask for permission for the first time the user runs the app. Your app will be able to use the location in background after obtaining the permission but ios will remind user from time to time that your app is using location service.

I have answered the post keeping iOS 8 in mind. For more details please read the section "Give apps permission to use your location" after visit the following link: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT203033